# What is the difference between JavaScript and JSX?

Tags: reactjs

I am pretty new to React, I find most tutorial talked about JSX, I have not learnt any JSX syntax, but I am wondering if the main usage difference between JavaScript and JSX in React is only on the HTML-like syntax? Or what else should pay attention to?

Comment: JSX *is* the html-like syntax.

Comment: @DavinTryon Thanks, so even if I put a <script type="text/jsx"> only the html-ish part is belong to JSX, other than that, the browser still treat it as JS? I wonder if I save a script including JSX as JS file, why the browser still be able to tell?

Comment: @kuan it will tell, and then give syntax errors on the JSX parts, since that would be invalid JS

Comment: @DavinTryon Thanks, so basically, I need to save it as .jsx file?

Comment: @Kuan - It should be saved as a javascript file. JSX is the name of the syntax, but [as the page I linked to in my comment below says](https://facebook.github.io/jsx/), it is not a language in and of itself, and it's not actually a part of javascript; it's merely an extension to the Javascript language.

Answer (score 40):

JS is standard javascript, JSX is an HTML-like syntax that you can use with React to (theoretically) make it easier and more intuitive to create React components. [As the docs say](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#why-jsx), the only purpose is to make it easier to create React components... there's not much else there. Without JSX, creating large, nested HTML documents using JS syntax would be a large pain in the rear; JSX simply makes that process easier.

Comment: Thanks, so even if I put a <script type="text/jsx"> only the html-ish part is belong to JSX, other than that, the browser still treat it as JS?

Comment: [You would never do that](https://facebook.github.io/jsx/). JSX is a transpiled language, interpreted by React preprocessors. It would be identified by `type="text/javascript"` as you would for any other javascript code.

Answer (score 16):

By default, every JSX syntax turns into JS function calls, i.e change to Javascript.

JSX helps to write much easier and cleaner code.

Example:

> **JSX Code:**

```
const App = () => {
    return <div>Hello world!</div>
}
```

> **Equivalent JS Code:**

```
const App = () => {
  return React.createElement("div", null, "Hello world!");
};
```

you can check out [Babel is a JavaScript compiler.](https://babeljs.io/repl), select react in the presets option to see actually how it turns out each line.

Answer (score 4):

**JavaScript** is just like any normal programming language without any additional library or framework. It can also be referred to as pure/vanilla JavaScript.

On the other hand, **JSX** is the **syntactic sugar** in JavaScript, a syntactic sugar is a syntax within a programming language that is designed to make things easier to read or to express. JSX is mostly used in JavaScript along with library/framework support like in **ReactJS** or **ReactNative**.

**JSX Example**

*Component written using **JSX**:*

```
const MyComponent = () => { 
  return <div> 
    <p>This is not HTML...!</p> 
    <p>Wait...Is this JavaScript?</p> 
    <p>No, What the hell is this?</p> 
    <p>This is JSX.</p> 
  </div> 
}
```

*In case we don’t want to use **JXS** then the corresponding code for the above code snippet will look like.*

```
const MyComponent = () => { 
  return React.createElement("div", null, React.createElement("p", null, "This is not HTML...!"), React.createElement("p", null, "Wait...Is this JavaScript?"), React.createElement("p", null, "No, What the hell is this?"), React.createElement("p", null, "This is JSX.")); 
};
```

**Reads:**

[Syntactic sugar - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar)

[Introducing JSX – React](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)

Answer (score 3):

With a JSX compiler, you can transform JSX expressions to calls to [`React.createElement`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.cloneelement). This is a more convenient way to achieve what has previously been accomplished with inlined HTML files as `SCRIPT` tags and, indeed, there are other JSX compilers that are not bound to React.

To give you a clear example, try looking at the following JSX code as it's compiled to JS via [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=%20%20%20%20import%20React%20from%20'react'%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20var%20Foo%20%3D%20React.createClass(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20render()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ad%20postea%20vocent%20equidem.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B):

```
import React from 'react';

var Foo = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          Ad postea vocent equidem.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, so basically the finally goal is to turn everything not in JS syntax into JS syntax, there is no JSX interpretor. RIght?

Answer (score 2):

Here you will see the basic difference of js and jsx

JavaScript example

```js
let element = React.createElement('h1', {}, 'This is JavaScript')
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
```

JSX equivalent

```js
let element = <h1>This is JSX</h1>
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Answer (score 1):

[JSX](https://facebook.github.io/jsx/) is an XML-like syntax extension to ECMAScript and not necessarily tied to React at all. 
React is just the transpiler, the engine that turns a tree of JSX into valid JavaScript. 
There are other transpilers like React that has JSX syntax as well, [JSXDom](https://github.com/vjeux/jsxdom) and [MercuryJSX](https://github.com/Raynos/mercury-jsx). JSX does not conform to any XML or HTML specification or is apart of ECMAScript in anyway and was invented at Facebook.

The reasoning behind JSX was that Facebook wanted to have one type of syntax extension that developers could rally behind by have a clear and concise specification and hopefully minimise of yet another "language".

Comment: a transpiler is a tool like babel; react is a library

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, JSX can be considered as writing HTML in JavaScript. If we have to write HTML without JSX, it involves writing lengthy code to create a DOM element and which is slightly complex to understand.

React documentation provides various examples and scenarios : https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html

Answer (score 0):

JSX is the stuff that looks like HTML and it tells React to either create a normal HTML element or show another component.

If it's telling React to create a normal HTML element, it looks like this:

```
export default function App() {

  return (
    <div>
     <h1>Howdy!</h1>
     <ul>
      <li>Samantha</li>
      <li>Alex</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If it's telling React to show another component, it looks like this:

```
export default function App() {

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Your friends</h1>
      <ContactList />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSX is a syntax extension for JavaScript. It allows you to write HTML-like code in your JavaScript files and helps you to create reusable UI components.

**Here is an example of JSX code**:

```
const element = <h1>Hello, world!</h1>;
```

JSX is not valid JavaScript code, so it needs to be transformed into JavaScript code that the browser can understand. This transformation is usually done using a transpiler such as Babel.

On the other hand, JavaScript (JS) is a programming language that is used for web development, among other things. It is a language that is executed by the browser or server-side runtime environments like Node.js.

**Here is an example of JavaScript code:**

```
const a = 10;
const b = 20;
const c = a + b;
console.log(c); // Outputs: 30
```

JSX is often used in combination with React, a JavaScript library for building user interfaces, to create reusable UI components. The React library provides a method called ReactDOM.render() that can be used to render JSX elements into the DOM.

```
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello, world!</h1>, document.getElementById('root'));
```