# React is not defined ReferenceError? I am using webpack and webpack-dev-server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, react-dom

this is my **jsx**:

```
 var React = require('react');
  var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
  ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>hello world</h1>,
    document.getElementById('content')
  )
```

I build with webpack to `build/bundle.js` &
I import `bundle.js` into `index.html`

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  ┊ <meta charset="utf-8">
  ┊ <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  ┊ <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  ┊ <div id="content"></div>
  ┊ <script src="./build/bundle.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when I ran `webpack-dev-server`, chrome console error:
`bundle.js:57 Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined`
I am sure, I have run `npm install react`
[image]

how can I fix it?(-_-)ゞ゛

Comment: Did you run `npm start` and saw hows its running on command line?

Comment: what's your webpack.config.js? did you set react preset?

Comment: @bitsMix Yes，I set preset in .babelrc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add this into your `app.js` not `.jsx`

```
var React = require('react');
  var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
  ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>hello world</h1>,
    document.getElementById('content')
  )
```

JSX is a transpiled language, interpreted by React components. So, there has to be React in app.js for React components to interpret the jsx!!

Comment: @nataila .jsx is half html/css and javascript, where as .js is pure javascript. You must have react in your app.js, JSX is transformed into React.createElement() calls, thus React is required in scope to handle them.

Comment: Whether it is app.js or app.jsx, it doesn't matter unless the OP is building the files with correct configuration in webpack.config.js. After all the syntax is JSX only

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri But if I want to use `JSX`, how can I config it in my `webpack.config.js`?

Comment: If you post your webpack config maybe, I can help.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri It does matter a lot. JSX is a transpiled language, interpreted by React components. So, there has to be React in app.js for React components to interpret the jsx!! Please see this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33042923/react-beginner-confuse-about-difference-between-javascript-and-jsx

Answer (score 0):

JSX syntax and ES6, are not supported in all the browsers.

Hence, if we are using them in the React code, we need to use a tool which translates them to the format that has been supported by the browsers. Babel is one such tool

Webpack uses loaders to translate the file before bundling them

To setup, install the following npm packages

```
npm i babel-loader babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react -S
```

The babel-preset-es2015 and babel-preset-react are plugins being used by the babel-loader to translate ES6 and JSX syntax respectively.

The next step is telling Webpack to use the babel-loader while bundling the files

```
// Existing Code ....
var config = {
  // Existing Code ....
  module : {
    loaders : [
      {
        test : /\.jsx?/,
        include : APP_DIR,
        loader : 'babel'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The loaders property takes an array of loaders,below I have used just `babel-loader`. Each loader property should specify what are the file extension it has to process via the test property. .js and .jsx files can be configured using the regular expression as `/\.jsx?/`

Final **webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
  devtool: "inline-sourcemap",
  entry: "./js/client.js",
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy'],
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/src/",
    filename: "client.min.js"
  },
  plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        'fetch': 'imports?this=>global!exports?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch'
      })
  ] 
};
```