# Distinguish between Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to understand some JavaScript code in an App.js file for my react native app. I want to know if the code  of`<AppLoading/> <View>` components are considered HTML code or JavaScript code?

```
export class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoadingComplete: false,
  };

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isLoadingComplete && !this.props.skipLoadingScreen) {
      return (
        <AppLoading
          startAsync={this._loadResourcesAsync}
          onError={this._handleLoadingError}
          onFinish={this._handleFinishLoading}
        />
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="default" />}
          <AppNavigator />
        <View/>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: It is a Javascript class and inside render method it's JSX

Comment: It is neither `.js` nor `.html` code. It is [`.jsx`](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html), a JavaScript syntax extension.

Comment: This syntax is called JSX. If you want to learn more about the difference here is a good link for the same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33042923/react-beginner-confuse-about-difference-between-javascript-and-jsx

Answer (score 2):

It's a syntax extension to Javascript called JSX. [You can read about it here](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html).

You can think about it more or less like regular HTML, but with a few important syntax differences (such as replacing `class` attributes with `className`, requiring a parent element if there's multiple siblings, etc.) and the ability to inject JS expressions inside curly brackets.