# How to use conditional to generate element on the page

Tags: reactjs

```
for (var k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
      if (k % 2 === 0) {
          weatherText = <div className="in_break">
      }
      weatherText += <div className="eachD" key={k}>
          <div>
            {
              countIt === 0 ? (currDate.getHours() > 12 ? "Tonight" : "Today") : dayOfWeek[weekDay]
            }
          </div>
          <div>
            {
              getDate
            }
          </div>
          <div>
            {
              <ReturnIcon />
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      if (k % 2 === 0) {
          weatherText += </div>
      }
  }
```

What I am looking to do is group all the `eachD` by two inside the `in_break' div

But I keep getting:

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token 'weatherText = </div>'
```

This is the layout:

```
in_break
   eachD
   eachD
in_break
   eachD
   eachD
in_break
   eachD
   eachD
...
```

Please help me resolve my issue

Comment: why are you treating `weatherText` as if it contains text and not React elements?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33042923/what-is-the-difference-between-javascript-and-jsx

Comment: It's only React elements.... unless i am wrong?

Comment: and what does `weatherText += <div />` do? there's a reason the accepted answer works and `weatherText += <div />` does not.

Comment: It was technically a closing tag for the opening tab up top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

I hope this find it's way to your demand:

```
setWeatherTextItems = (countId, currDate, dayOfWeek, weekDay, getDate) => {
  // you make sure all the variables such like countId and currDate are available inside this function.
  const items = [];
  for (var k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
    items.push(
      <div className="eachD" key={k}>
        <div>
          {countIt === 0
            ? currDate.getHours() > 12
              ? "Tonight"
              : "Today"
            : dayOfWeek[weekDay]}
        </div>
        <div>{getDate}</div>
        <div>{<ReturnIcon />}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return items;
}

renderInBreak = () => {
  const items = this.setWeatherTextItems();
  const inBreakItems = [];
  let breakBlock = [];
  let newBreak = false;
  items.forEach((textItem, index) => { //1
    if(!newBreak) {
      breakBlock.push(textItem);
      if(index + 1 === items.length){
        inBreakItems.push(breakBlock);
      }
    } else {
      inBreakItems.push(breakBlock);
      breakBlock = [];
      breakBlock.push(textItem);

     //without this condition check, the last element will be left out of an odd array length
      if(index + 1 === items.length) {
          inBreakItems.push(breakBlock)
      }
    }
    if(index % 2) newBreak = true; //false
    else newBreak = false; //false
  });

  return inBreakItems.map(twoTextWeatherItems => (
    <div className="in_break">
      {twoTextWeatherItems}
    </div>
  ))
}

render(){
  <div>
    {this.renderInBreak()}
  </div>
}
```

---

**OLD**

React is supposed to handle things differently, maybe this will work:

Define a method in your component that will set your items:

```
setWeatherTextItems = (countId, currDate, dayOfWeek, weekDay, getDate) => {
  // you make sure all the variables such like countId and currDate are available inside this function.
  const items = [];
  for (var k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
    items.push(
      <div className="eachD" key={k}>
        <div>
          {countIt === 0
            ? currDate.getHours() > 12
              ? "Tonight"
              : "Today"
            : dayOfWeek[weekDay]}
        </div>
        <div>{getDate}</div>
        <div>{<ReturnIcon />}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return items;
}
```

in your `render` method, or where you are willing to render these items:

```
render(){
  <div className="in_break">{this.setWeatherTextItems()}</div>
}
```

Read more about [how to render things in a loop](https://flaviocopes.com/react-how-to-loop/).

You can add the conditions you want inside the for loop, or where it makes sense to you.

Comment: Thanks but that won't work. I want every two div to be inside `in_break`

Comment: you want each `in_break` `div` to have two items?

Comment: Yes... Because with CSS at certain width I am doing to display the groups separateley

Comment: That works but if I have 5 items, it only keeps 4 and gets ride of the 5th one.

Comment: Sorry for that, I wasn't able to test the code because I'm kind in a rush, I have handled the case and edited the code under **UPDATED** in the same answer.

Comment: Yeah sorry i just realized the final object is only in the ELSE statement that's why. I also fixed it as well.

Comment: Yes, that exactly what happened. good it works, i'm glad, I'll be updating the answer tomorrow with a better logic if you want me to do.

Comment: Weird that didn't work, it still skips the last one for some reason.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196489/discussion-between-sultan-h-and-si8).

Comment: Updated with your addition! good luck, it was a pleasue, thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I also edited with comment for any future visitor experiencing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the logic would work in a react environment but as far as I can see from your plain code when you are going to add the 'in_break' div aren't you just assigning the whole whetherText again instead of joining text to it?

```
  Shouldn't this:
  if (k % 2 === 0) {
      weatherText = </div>
  }
  be written like this?
  if (k % 2 === 0) {
      weatherText += </div>
  }
```

Edit following the typo correction:

```
I tried to run your code on codepen to have a quicker and easier understanding on how to find a solution. 
I created an helper function with your code then I returned 
<div className="Container" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: weatherText}}></div>
This enables you to have the result you are looking for. Only the even elements have the 'in_break' class.
```

Hope this helped and let me know if this is not correct.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/dpgian/pen/EBzRmX

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. Thanks. Fixed it

Comment: Oh right. Fair enough :) There is a typo on top as well in the other if statement, but at least we know that's not the problem.

Comment: Edit with a possible solution

Comment: Thanks for the help :) +1